# Trying to repeat questions until user wants to stop

Tags: python, loops

I'm creating a code to find the area and type of a triangle after asking the user for the base height and sides. At the end of the code, I'm supposed to ask the user if they're done or want to enter another triangle and I know I need a while loop I just don't know where to put it so it's at the end of my code

#Programming HW

```
answer = input("Have another?")
while again != "y":

base = int(input("Enter base: "))
height = int(input("Enter height: "))
side1 = int(input("Enter side 1:  "))
side2 = int(input("Enter side 2:  "))
side3 = int(input("Enter side 3:  "))
area = (base*height) / 2

certain_type = []
if side1 == side2 == side3:
    certaintype = "Equilateral triangle"
elif side1==side2 or side2==side3 or side1==side3:
    certaintype = "isosceles triangle"
else:
    certaintype = "Scalene triangle"


print('This %d of the triangle is %s' % (certaintype, area) )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to come at it, but the important part is to have a condition associated with your `while` loop that will be `True` to begin with and stay `True` so long as their is more work to be done, but will switch to `False` when there is no more work to be done.  The example below shows one way to do that with little change to your existing code.

Example:

```
more_work_to_do = True
while more_work_to_do:

    base = int(input("Enter base: "))
    height = int(input("Enter height: "))
    side1 = int(input("Enter side 1:  "))
    side2 = int(input("Enter side 2:  "))
    side3 = int(input("Enter side 3:  "))
    area = (base*height) / 2

    certain_type = []
    if side1 == side2 == side3:
        certaintype = "Equilateral triangle"
    elif side1==side2 or side2==side3 or side1==side3:
        certaintype = "isosceles triangle"
    else:
        certaintype = "Scalene triangle"

    print('This %d of the triangle is %s' % (certaintype, area) )
    
    user_input = input("Have another go [y/n]? ")
    more_work_to_do = user_input != "y"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`f-strings`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) and [`set().`](https://realpython.com/python-sets/)

```
answer = input("Have another task to do? Enter y for no ")
while answer != "y":
    base, height, side1, side2, side3 = int(input("Enter base: ")), int(input("Enter height: ")), int(
        input("Enter side 1:  ")), int(input("Enter side 2:  ")), int(input("Enter side 3:  "))
    area = (base*height) / 2
    unique_side = len(set([side3, side1, side2]))
    certain_type = ["equilateral", "isosceles", "scalene"][unique_side - 1]
    print(f"The area of {certain_type} is {area}")
    answer = input("Have another task to do ? Enter y for no ")
```